# PySpark function to create custom output based on multiple columns of dataframe

Tags: pyspark, lambda, user-defined-functions, rdd

I have a source pyspark dataframe as per below structure:

| A | B | C | D | E | F | G |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 145 | 589 | 1 | 1 |  | 12 | 25 |
| 145 | 589 | 1 | 2 | 1ad34 |  |  |
| 145 | 589 | 1 | 3 | 257 | 18 | 55 |
| 145 | 589 | 2 | 1 |  | 12 | 25 |
| 145 | 589 | 2 | 2 |  | 22 | 45 |
| 145 | 589 | 2 | 3 |  |  |  |
| 145 | 589 | 3 | 1 |  | 32 | 55 |
| 145 | 589 | 3 | 2 |  |  |  |

Table Overview:

1. Combination of A and B column will have indexed C column. For each indexed C column, we will have D column. Concatenation of A|B|C|D identifies a unique record.
2. For the below complete, dataframe  check if E column is set at any point of dataframe records traversal. If yes, return the first numeric value (eg 257 should result and 1ad34 should be ignored ) This will be priority 1 operation.
3. If column E is never set, return the concatenation of F and G for the very last row combination. If 257 would have never been set on column E, then return 3255 based on 145|589|3|1.

Test Case 1 : Priority column E contains few values. The very first numeric one is 257. So our output should be 257 for 145|589.

Test Case 2 : Priority column E is completely empty, then pick up the most last concatenated value of F and G column which should result as 3255 for 145|589

I have implemented a pyspark code for this as below:

```
def get_resulting_id(grouped_A_B_df):
    try :
        out=''
        first_E_val_df=grouped_A_B_df.filter(col("E").cast("int").isNotNull()).first()
        if ( first_E_val_df):
            return first_E_val_df["E"]
        unique_C = [x.C for x in grouped_A_B_df.select('C').distinct().collect()]
        for uniq in unique_C :
            for row in uniq.rdd.toLocalIterator():
                out=str(row['F'])+str(row['G'])
    except:
        raise Exception("Func failed")
    return out
```

Since the source dataframe is having 20 million records, i do not want to use localiterator in priority2 condition, any possible way to speed up the operation. The source dataframe partitioned by combination of column A and B will give the subset dataframe. I want my custom function to be applied on that subset dataframe and return the result for each subset dataframe.

Comment: what is the expected output ? a new column in the current dataframe ? or a local python object i.e. a pandas df or list ?

Comment: Pandas df will be fine.

Comment: if you could give a better sample input, with case E and case F+G, that'd be great ! (we really do not need that many lines, just relevant ones) - [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Thanks steven! It helps, i was wondering how to get the first numeric value from E column with the coalesce and partitioning. Let's say 145|589|1|2 has value 123abc, then we need to ignore that and get the first numeric value. first(col("E").cast(DecimalType()).isNull(), ignorenulls=True) might not be right here because it will make first expression as boolean and second expression as string, am i correct?
Any way out for that?

Comment: If you only want numeric value, you just have to cast as int and cast it back to string : replace `F.first("E", ignorenulls=True)` with `F.first(F.col("E").cast("int").cast("str"), ignorenulls=True)`. But again, it is not in your sample data, so please update your example with Minimal, Reproductible example.

Comment: Thanks a ton Steven! You have been really helpful, really appreciate it. I have updated the above use case better now with test case 1 and test case 2 description.

Comment: One  more thing just curious to know from knowledge perspective, if we need to extend it based on different column X lets say, and if X=0 then populate priroity 1 value and if X=1 then populate priority 2 value. How should we handle the F.when condition in the coalesce?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure to understand exactly what is your expected output based on the sample input data you gave. I tried your function, and the output is '257' so here is my full pyspark code that should provide the same output:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F, Window as W

df.select(
    "A",
    "B",
    F.coalesce(
        F.first("E", ignorenulls=True).over(
            W.partitionBy("A", "B")
            .orderBy("C", "D")
            .rowsBetween(W.unboundedPreceding, W.unboundedFollowing)
        ),
        F.last(F.concat(F.col("F"), F.col("G")), ignorenulls=True).over(
            W.partitionBy("A", "B")
            .orderBy("C", "D")
            .rowsBetween(W.unboundedPreceding, W.unboundedFollowing)
        ),
    ).alias("out"),
).distinct().show()

+---+---+---+                                                                   
|  A|  B|out|
+---+---+---+
|145|589|257|
+---+---+---+
```

You can replace `.show()` with `.toPandas()` if you need a pandas df as output.